# Why did ulimit not stop my fork bomb that was running as the superuser?

Tags: fork, ulimit

I'm studying the fork bombs and I have some troubles to find a way to protect from this type of attack.
As far as I know there are two possible solutions:

1. ulimit
2. cgroup

I'm studying the first one on the following machine

```
uname -a
Linux kali 4.9.59-v7_Re4son-Kali-Pi+ #1 SMP Fri Jan 26 16:45:14 CST 2018 armv7l GNU/Linux
```

I've modified `/etc/security/limits.conf` with the following line

```
root        hard    nproc           20
```

After a reboot and a shell access as root user, I obtain:

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 7346
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 16384
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 20
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Trying the following fork bomb

```
 :(){ : | : & };:
```

I obtain a Denial-of-Service and I don't understand the rationale behind it. With my configuration I should prevent this attack but it does not work.
What's wrong?

Comment: As a best practice, you never work as root, much less with these kind of things. Limit a normal user, for starters.´

Comment: You're right, but this is only for testing purposes

Comment: I am still suggesting to study and limit processes with a  normal user. root is a special user with much less restrictions.

Comment: `ulimit` works well with non root users (I have tested it), but my question regards a root user